# Wordpress Updating Attachment Data

Tags: wordpress, media-library

I'm attempting to add a feature to a plugin that extends media management. This feature would allow you to rename an attachment file. I've been able to complete this with the following code.

```
public function update_attachment_filename( $post_ID ) {

    // Get path to existing file
    $file = get_attached_file( $post_ID );
    $path = pathinfo( $file );

    // Generate new file name
    $file_updated = $path['dirname'] . '/' . $_POST['update_filename'] . '.' . $path['extension'];

    // Update the name and reference to file
    rename( $file, $file_updated );
    update_attached_file( $post_ID, $file_updated );

}
```

While the original file gets renamed using the above method, all additional image sizes defined in the plugins/theme are not updated. I'm struggling to figure out the best way to accomplish this task.

I've looked into `wp_update_attachment_metadata()` and `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()` but am unsure whether they will give me the desired functionality.

Additionally I've looked into something such as:

```
$file_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $post_ID );

foreach( $file_meta['sizes'] as $image ) {

    // Do something

}
```

Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to utilize both the `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()` and the `wp_update_attachment_metadata()` function to achieve the desired end result.

```
public function update_attachment_filename( $post_ID ) {

        if( isset( $_POST['update_filename'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['update_filename'] ) ) {

            // Get path to existing attachment
            $file = get_attached_file( $post_ID );
            $path = pathinfo( $file );

            // Create new attachment name
            $file_updated = $path['dirname'] . '/' . $_POST['update_filename'] . '.' . $path['extension'];

            // Update the attachment name
            rename( $file, $file_updated );
            update_attached_file( $post_ID, $file_updated );

            // Update attachment meta data
            $file_updated_meta = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $post_ID, $file_updated );
            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $post_ID, $file_updated_meta );

        }

    }
```